# Magento 2.3 REST API: How to update shipment?

Tags: magento2.3, rest-api, shipment-tracking

I need to add **carrier code** and **tracking number** to the shipment by REST API.

For this, I am trying 2 different codes which I found from the search as below. But it doesn't update anything, not display any error and return the same array.

1. I don't know what should be **order_id**, **parent_id** and **entity_id**. I am using different ids from the order and shipment URL.

   ```
   $shiptrack = [
   "entity" => [
   "order_id" => 6298,
   "parent_id" => 6298,
   "entity_id" => 12594,
   "weight"=> 0,
   "qty"=> 0,
   "description"=> "Tracking code Description",
   "track_number"=> "1234567",
   "title"=> "Custom Tracking Code",
   "carrier_code"=> "custom"
   ]
   ];
   ```

2.Tried all **ids** from the order and shipment URL.

```
$shiptrack = [ 
"items"=> [ 
        [ 
            "order_item_id"=>5813, 
            "qty"=> 0 
        ] 
    ], 
"notify" => true, 
"appendComment" => true, 
"comment" => [ 
    "extension_attributes" => [], 
    "comment" => "Item(s) has been shipped", 
    "is_visible_on_front" => 0 
], "tracks" => [ 
        [ 
            "extension_attributes" => [], 
            "track_number" => $trackingNumber, 
            "title" => $shipTitle, 
            "carrier_code" => $carrierCode 
        ] 
    ] 
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inorder to add tracking information to a shipment you need to make a POST call to the following link

> {base_url}/V1/shipment/track

Sample Body :

> ```
> {
>  "entity": {
>  "order_id": 291,
>  "parent_id": 121,
>  "description": "Tracking code Descripton",
>  "track_number": "123456789",
>  "title": "FEDEX",
>  "carrier_code": "fedex"
>  }
> }
> ```

Here `order_id` is the one you see when you open Order View Page in Admin. See Ref Image, here Red marked is order id.
[image]

And `parent_id` is the one you see when you open Shipment View Page in Admin (for which you are going to add tracking info). See Ref Image, here Red marked is parent id.
[image]

Make sure you do not forget to add Authentication Bearer to header of your request. Hope if finds you helpful.

Comment: It's worked. Thank you, Abdul.